# Redis wait for key to be cached in GET request

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, jedis, http-caching

I have two REST end-points

1. POST request, this request does some long running task and fills the key-value pair in the cache.
2. GET request this gets the data from the cache corresponding to a particular key.

Now sometimes Spring-boot server gets the GET request even before the post request has finished processing, so I want some way such that the GET request waits for the key to get cached in the server. If within 1-second the key does not get cached null is returned from the GET end point.

Can anyone please help me with some solution or a way to solve this problem.

Comment: Which redis client are you using to talk to the redis server?

Comment: @HarshankBansal I am using jedis

Comment: Afaik jedis is a synchronous client, so why don't you wait for your post request to finish (at that point the key will be present due to the sync client) before sending the get request?

Comment: Maybe you can configure a `@Retryable` with a delay in case you get a null.